# Prove that $C^1[0,1]$ is space of continuously differentaible function with $C_1$ norm is separable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

$C^1[0,1]$ is space of continuously differentiable function with $C_1$ norm.Then the space $ (C^1[0, 1],)$ is a separable space. I am thinking of c^1[0,1] is subset of c[0,1], and c[0,1] is separable. so is c^1[0,1]. is my argument make sense? If not could you please provide me some hints.

Comment: Separability asks for a dense, countable subset. Density depends on the choice of norms and the norms for $C^0$ and $C^1$ are different. However, one way to prove that $C^0$ is separable uses the Bernstein polynomials which are not only approximating functions w.r.t. the $C^0$ norm, but also the $C^1$ one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial

Comment: No your argument has problems. The metric on $C^1$ is not the metric it inherits from $C^0.$

Answer (score 2):

Write functions in $C^1$ as
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xf'(t)dt
$$
with $f'\in C^0$ to find that this provides a parametrization of $C^1$ by $\Bbb R×C^0$. Show that this is an homeomorphism. Only then can you use the separability of $C^0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\mathcal P _{\mathbb Q}$ be the set of polynomials with rational coefficients. Let $f \in C^1.$ Then as you probably know, we can approximate $f'$ in $C^0$ by polynomials in $\mathcal P _{\mathbb Q}.$ We should then be able to approximate $f$ in $C^1$ polynomials of the form

$$r+ \int_0^x p(t)\,dt,\,\,r\in \mathbb Q, \, p \in \mathcal P _{\mathbb Q}.$$